# Continuously Compare Cells in Two Columns Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that continually updates Column G with data from the internet.

I have Column K that has fixed values.

How do I watch these two columns so that when G > K for any row, Google Apps Script will send an email?

(I know how to send the email, and my spreadsheet is currently updating appropriately, I'm just not able to trigger the email send...)

Comment: Can you be more specific about how your data is coming into the spreadsheet?

Comment: E.G.: =GOOGLEFINANCE("currency:USDEUR")

Comment: You will need to use a timebased trigger.

Comment: I got that part... it's the "compare two columns for changes in any row" part

Comment: How about storing a copy of those two columns on another sheet and then comparing them on every trigger.